# Triangular arrow head in xypic

Tags: xy-pic

Let us consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{A\ar[rr] && B}$
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

but I want the following arrowhead style using [`xypic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic):

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain something like this

[image]

by defining a new direction arrow (requires `amssymb`)

```
\newdir{|>}{-<5pt,0pt>{\blacktriangleright}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newdir{|>}{-<5pt,0pt>{\blacktriangleright}}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{A\ar@{-|>}[rr] && B}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be `\llap` the `\blacktriangleright`?

Comment: @Manuel Have you tried it with `\llap`? It doesn't look good.