# Rotatable triangular arrowheads in xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic

I want an answer to [Triangular arrow head in xypic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226654/triangular-arrow-head-in-xypic) that plays nicely with directions other than `r`, `rr`, `rrr`, etc.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newdir{|>}{-<5pt,0pt>{\blacktriangleright}}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{
A&B&C\\
D&O\ar@{-|>}[ul]\ar@{-|>}[ur]\ar@{-|>}[u]\ar@{-|>}[l]\ar@{-|>}[r]\ar@{-|>}[dl]\ar@{-|>}[d]\ar@{-|>}[dr]&E \\
F&G&H
}$
\end{document}
```

This shows up as

[image: Image of the above code]

How can I make the arrow heads rotate with the direction?

Comment: How about Tikz?

Comment: If one has decades diagrams drawn in xypic, like I do, tikz is not a solution to this problem.  Of course I draw my *new* diagrams in tikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to the more versatile and modern [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package (which has a large provision of arrow tipsa and dditionally gives you access to all the variety of arrow tips from the `arrows.meta` library), here's an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzcdset{
  arrow style={tikz,diagrams={>=Triangle}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A & B & C \\
D & O \ar[ur]\ar[u]\ar[ul]\ar[r]\ar[l]\ar[dr]\ar[d]\ar[dl] & E \\
F & G & H
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if want to use `\blacktriangleright` as arrow tip you can easily do it with the appropriate rotation:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\tikzset{amstri/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=blacktriangleright]}}
\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>=amstri}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A & B & C \\
D & O\ar[ur]\ar[u]\ar[ul]\ar[r]\ar[l]\ar[dr]\ar[d]\ar[dl] & E\\
F & G & H
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are Ok with Tikz then this is a possible solution,

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        place/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3mm},
        >=latex,->,line width=1pt
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \node[place] (A)               {A};
     \node[place] (B) [right=of A]  {B};
     \node[place] (C) [right=of B]  {C};
     \node[place] (D) [below=of A]  {D};
     \node[place] (O) [below=of B]  {O};
     \node[place] (E) [below=of C]  {E};
     \node[place] (F) [below=of D]  {F};
     \node[place] (G) [below=of O]  {G};
     \node[place] (H) [below=of E]  {H};

     \draw (O) -- (A);
     \draw (O) -- (B);
     \draw (O) -- (C);
     \draw (O) -- (D);
     \draw (O) -- (E);
     \draw (O) -- (F);
     \draw (O) -- (G);
     \draw (O) -- (H);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]