# Circle and colored-arrow in xypic

Tags: color, xy-pic

I'm using `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}` and I'd like to create a circle for `$\overline{D_1^n}$`, I'd like to color in red the `$f\circ\pi$`-arrow, I'd like also to shade the `$S^n/\mathbb{Z}^2$`. I inserted the **dsfrac**-funcion, where **dsfrac** stands for

```
\newcommand{\dsfrac}[2]{\displaystyle{\Huge{\sfrac{#1}{#2}}}}
```

The code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}

\Large

\newcommand{\dsfrac}[2]{\displaystyle{\Huge{\sfrac{#1}{#2}}}}

\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}

\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}

\begin{equation}
\xymatrix{{\overline{D_1^n}}\ar@{^{(}->}[rr]^{i}\ar@{>>}[d]_{\pi_1}\ar@{^{(}->>}[drr]_{f\circ\pi_1}^{\pi_2\circ i}&&S^n\ar@{>>}[d]^{\pi_ 2}\\\dsfrac{\overline{D_1^n}}{\!\!\sim}\ar@{^{(}->>}[rr]^{f}_{\cong}&&\boxed{\dsfrac{S^n}{\Z^2}}\ar@{=}[r]&\P^n\tonde{\R}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `tikz-cd`, which makes this somewhat easier. In particular, you can use `cells=nodes` to get your box and circle.

There are a few problems with the way you are changing type size in your code. If you want to enlarge the whole diagram, use the `adjustbox` package and

`\adjustbox{scale=1.5,center}{\begin{tikzcd}...\end{tikzcd}}`

I wasn't sure what you meant by shading the `$S^n/\mathbb{Z}^2$`, so I made it blue. Easy to change that.

To change the arrowheads, add `arrow style=tikz, >={Triangle[length=2mm]}` to the `tikzcd` options. You can adjust the `length` and `width` of the arrowheads however you like. You might also consider `>={latex}` as a similar option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrow style=tikz, >={Triangle[length=2mm]}, cells={nodes={inner sep=2mm}}, row sep=1cm]
\overline{D_1^n}\arrow[rr, hook, "i"]\arrow[drr, red, hook, two heads, text=black, "\pi_2\circ i", "f\circ\pi_1"']\arrow[d, two heads, "\pi_1"'] 
    && S^n\arrow[d, two heads, "\pi_2"]\\
|[draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt]|\raisebox{.5ex}{$\overline{D_1^n}$}\Big/\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\sim$}\arrow[rr, hook, two heads, "f", "\cong"'] 
    && |[draw, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=2pt, text=blue]|\raisebox{.5ex}{$S^n\!$}\Big/\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\Z^2$}\arrow[r, equals] & \P^n(\R) 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I expressed to desire a solution with xymatrix not with tikzcd. Sandi G thank you for your answer, but I can't vote it. I'd like another solution, please. Thanks in advanced at all.

Comment: I can also accept solution with `\begin{xy}...\end{xy}`, thanks again

Comment: @Puck: I understand you wanted an `xy` solution, but `tikz-cd` is much more commonly used nowadays. It is more user-friendly and repairs many of the spacing issues that are problematic in `xy`. Other users will likely find a `tikz-cd` solution helpful in the future. You certainly don't have to accept my answer (or even vote for it) but I find the downvote highly inappropriate.

Comment: At the end I accepted your answer, principally because I realized that `xymatrix` of `xy-pic`-package is more limited then `tikz-cd` one. If you edit (even banally) your answer I could upvote it. I would pray you not to be offended. Thank you very much

Comment: But about arrows of your photo, does exist a way to improve the quality of arrows? I mean, I'd like to have the arrow with triangular tip, as in [THIS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226654/triangular-arrow-head-in-xypic?rq=1). Is it possible, thank you so much (P.S.: You can edit your answer with my last request, thx)

Comment: @Puck: To be clear, you should upvote an answer if it is helpful *to you*. You should only downvote an answer if you don't think it is helpful *to anyone*. I will update my answer with your arrowheads.

Comment: Now here we are, perfect! Thank you very much